# Stop redirection in browser. I will stay in app

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, codeigniter

I have created a website. and make a web view of this website in app. so android application shows a mobile website in app. but while having use app.. there are some functionalities to make payment and i will use a third party payment gateway.

When it will hit for the payment, third party gateway links open in mobile's browser not in app. So after the payment it shows an error bcz there is no session in browser. It's all in app.
coding is done in codeigniter.

So how i will redirect payment gateway in app not in browser. So i could not get error.

Comment: you can use this in android app, its like webview
https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code looks like but you can use Intent to set which link to inside or outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply tap into whatever the payment gateway returns and find out if the payment has been completed

Since yopu ve not specified on the payment gateway lets assume an example of paypall.

1. Paypall has an  [instant payment notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) that you listenm o when payment is completed
2. his will basically send a confirmation to your server that tells you it has gone through.

   3. Listen for this in the server(php codeignter) and send a notification to your android app that payment is completed.

So probably in your case check on the payment api's they can provide more details

Comment: we have just called a website in android app.. like web view in android app. not make an entire app

Comment: Ivbe checked it out and seems to be a paid version so i dont have the api. Buti can see from https://www.atomtech.in/payment-gateway-integration.html they have an sdk kit for mobile app whick can make your work even easier you dont have to open a mobile browser. If you still need the browser option i can see they also have payment integration for the website

Comment: since i dont have the actual sdk i may not be able to provide you with concrete example but a guideline maybe.

Comment: Also i believe from what hey display in the website in your case the android sdk would be much easier to work with.